# I can't make a Esc shortcut

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do a shortcut.

When the escape is clicked, should appear a message, but is not working.

I tried with the enter(13), and it worked:

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ENK9p/

```
function shortcuts(event) {
            if (event.which === 27) {
            alert('teste');
                event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        };

<textarea name='static' id='static' onkeypress="shortcuts(event);"></textarea>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uU668/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `keydown` event. As you have tagged jQuery, You should bind event using it.

```
$('#static').on('keydown', function (event) {
    if (event.which === 27) {
        alert('teste');
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uU668/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the jquery method, use Satpal's method. If you want to use plain javascript, you should change the event to `onkeydown` and make sure your function is defined in the head. In the fiddle you linked, your javascript is all wrapped in `onDomReady`, so it's not defined when the keydown event occurs.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fs26t/)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is example**: http://jsfiddle.net/ENK9p/1/

You can use keyup() methoed to detect ESC key press

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 27){
       alert("test");
    }
});
```